# mov -8(%rbp), %rax not updating %rax value

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att, stack-memory

Below is my assembly for the C code

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return a + b;
}
```

```
    .globl main
main:
  push  %rbp
  mov %rsp, %rbp
  mov   $1, %rax
  push  %rax
  mov   $2, %rax
  push  %rax
  mov   0(%rbp), %rax
  push  %rax
  mov   -8(%rbp), %rax
  pop   %rcx
  add   %rcx, %rax
  mov %rbp, %rsp
  pop %rbp
  ret
```

I am partially sure its the current mapping of C code to ASM. The issue am facing which I observed while running the assembled binary through GDB, is that:

```
mov -8(%rbp), %rax
```

doesn't update the value of `%rax` to 2.

The command I used for assembling the assembly code is:

```
gcc data/stage_5/valid/multiple_vars.s -o data/stage_5/valid/multiple_vars
```

Comment: Why do you think it would? `-8(%rbp)` contains `1`. Note that `push` decrements `rsp` **before** writing the operand into the stack.

Comment: Have you tried using GDB to examine memory? e.g. `x /1gx $rbp-8`, or a larger count and lower start address to examine more memory at once.

Comment: @Jester the stack at instruction `mov -8(%rbp), %rax` stack is `rbp -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 <- rsp`. So 0(%rbp) is 1 and -8(%rbp) should be 2.

Comment: No, `0%(rbp)` is the old `rbp` put on the stack by `push %rbp`.

Comment: Thanks finally got it, I seemed to have been confused by the fact that stack memory decreases with each push, so if I want to read the first element, I have to go for -8(%rbp) and read 8 bytes from there.